# Existence of matrix with certain property over a finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, finite-fields, trace

Let $F_p = \{0,1,2,...,p-1\}$ be field for a prime $p$. Does there exist a matrix $A$ with entries in $F_p$ such that $tr(A^k) = 0$ if $k=2,3,\ldots,p-1$ and $tr(A^k) \neq 0$ if $k=1$?

Comment: First assume the matrix is diagonal, then the trace is the sum of the eigenvalues, and the trace of $A^p$ is the sum of the p-th powers of the eigenvalues. But raising to the p-th power is additive in $\Bbb F_p$, so ...

Comment: Thanks! How about if $A$ has property $tr(A^k) = 0$ if $k = 1,p$ and $tr(A^k) \neq 0$ if $k = 2,3,...,p-1$?

Comment: To the question in the comment: Take $1<r<p$ such that $r$ is a multiplicative generator of $\Bbb F_p^*$. Then the $(p-r+1) \times (p-r+1)$-matrix 

$$A=\pmatrix{r &0&...&0\\ 0&1&...&0\\ &&...\\ 0&0&...&1}$$

(i.e. there are $p-r$ diagonal entries "$1$")

has trace $0$, but $tr(A^k)=r^k +p-r = r^{k-1}(r-1)\neq0$ mod $p$ for $2\le k\le p-1$. About the question in the post now, for $p=3$ the matrix $\pmatrix{2&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&1}$ does the job; for general $p$ I would have to think more.

Comment: I'm a bit curious. How did you run into this question? Particularly in light of your willingness to drop the assumption about  $tr(A^k)$ when $k=1$. It's still in a sense interesting. If $k=p-1$ were the exceptional exponent it could easily become boring though :-) Anyway, have you checked what Newton's identities now reveal about the eigenvalues of $A$ (to the extent that they apply in char $p$)?

Comment: Hi @JyrkiLahtonen. I'm currently working on an open problem related with PI-algebra and finite fields and one of my approach is using this conjecture of mine. I'm not really used to working around finite fields so I'm not really familiar to some in-depth results. Also, I'll check out the Newton's identities.

Comment: My current thinking is that examples should exist, but they may be difficult to exhibit. Thinking about eigenvalues. Consider the system of equations
$$\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_N&=&1\\ x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_N^2&=&0\\
\cdots\\
x_1^{p-1}+x_2^{p-1}+\cdots+x_N^{p-1}&=&0\end{array}\right.$$
For $N$ large enough, bounds from algebraic geometry over finite fields should imply that the system has solutions over $\Bbb{F}_{p^\ell}$ for large enough $\ell$. I also want $p\nmid \ell$. Then using a matrix with eigenvalues $x_i$ together with their conjugates should work.

Comment: (cont'd) Like, build a matrix with companion matrices of polynomials $p_i(T)=\prod_{j=0}^{\ell-1}(T-x_i^{p^j})$ as blocks. Or something like that. Gotta go. Coffee and cake being served!